# How to create CASE WHEN for the current DATE being larger than the date specified in another column (as a field) in Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to compare data preceding a particular date (as specificed in a dimension or metric) to that after that date using a dummy variable as a calculated field.

I tried filtering but it only allows me to filter on a *specific* date (hardcoded as the 03.10.2020 for example), not a date listed inside a metric (which is a column listing various dates, in this case specific to a landing page entry).

Ideally it would look like this:

CASE WHEN Date >= *Online since* THEN "1"
ELSE "0"

With "online since" being a column of dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Data Studio is a wonderful tool, but when you face these limitations you feel how much it is a working in progress.

In short, you need to be wise to workaround these limitations.

Create a column with the difference, in days, between dates:

```
Diff_Date_OnlineSince ---> DATE_DIFF(Date, Online since)
```

Then, use this column in your case statement:

```
New_Column            ---> CASE WHEN Diff_Date_OnlineSince >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

This way, you feed the monster with what it wants: a dimension compared to a literal value.  Mission accomplished!

Comment: Many thanks for the nifty workaround! Indeed, Data Studio seems like it is still work in progress. Unfortunately "Date" and "online since" in my case are from two different data sources joined together. When calculating a chart-specific field I can't refer to another chart-specific calculated field.

Comment: Indeed you faced a more complex situation. Can't you pre-process your data with BigQuery or something? This is what I do when Data Studio is not helping. I would say I rarely use Blended sources, because I think they're very difficult to maintain.